# Why isnt this maco inserting the date correctly?

Tags: excel

I am attempting to use this macro to insert the date and time into an active cell. I cannot find the documentation on how to do this with regards to the date formatting. The "ttttt" inserts the correct time. I want the date and time however. This is what I have, the commented out lines are those I have tried that don't work.

```
Sub time()
If Target.Address = ActiveCell.Address Then

'Target = Format(Now, "ttttt")
Target = Format(Now, "dddd:ttttt")
'Target = Format(Now, "ddddttttt")
'Target = Format(Now(), "ddddttttt")
'Target = Format(Now(), "m/d/yyyy hh:nn AM/PM")
'Target = Format(Now, "m/d/yyyy hh:mm AM/PM")

End If
End Sub
```

Comment: What format do you want to insert? Can't you just insert Now() and leave the formatting to the cell?

Comment: And in what event are you using this code? Target isn't defined here.

Comment: What I want the macro to do is, when the cell is clicked, it will insert the date and time.

Comment: any format as long as its the date and time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see no problem.  Running:

```
Sub dural()
    With ActiveCell
        .Value = Now
        .NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss"
    End With
End Sub
```

produces:

[image]

**EDIT#1:**

Based on your comments, I am going to consider a single cell, cell **B9**, and I will use a double-click rather than a single click.
I will use double-click because it is easier to trap the double-click event.
Place my previous code in a standard module.  In the worksheet code area we enter the following Event macro:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    If Intersect(Range("B9"), Target) Is Nothing Then
    Else
        Application.EnableEvents = False
            Call dural
            Cancel = True
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Because it is worksheet code, it is very easy to install and automatic to use:

1. right-click the tab name near the bottom of the Excel window
2. select View Code - this brings up a VBE window
3. paste the stuff in and close the VBE window

If you have any concerns, first try it on a trial worksheet.

If you save the workbook, the macro will be saved with it.
If you are using a version of Excel later then 2003, you must save
the file as .xlsm rather than .xlsx

To remove the macro:

1. bring up the VBE windows as above
2. clear the code out
3. close the VBE window

To learn more about Event Macros (worksheet code), see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/event.htm

Comment: Your macro is doing the same thing mine is, the date keeps coming up as 1/1/1900 .

Comment: @Oscalation  Then I cannot help you because I cannot replicate what you are seeing and I cannot imagine a configuration difference that would explain your result.

Comment: i think i  have narrowed it down to where im inserting my macro code. i used this http://ccm.net/faq/6279-excel-enter-current-time-in-a-cell-by-clicking-it    I think it has to do with where I am adding the code. When I just add a micro and use your code in the normal location, it works although it doesnt continue to insert the date continuously every time I click.

Comment: @Oscalation  See my **EDIT#1**